# "Here will be your logo" - any idea how to visually represent this to a client on a demo website?

Tags: website-design, layout, user-behavior, users, user-research

"Here will be your logo" - any idea how to visually represent this to a client on a demo website?

We are a company offering free demo of client's website, before going for a deal.

Although, the reason I am giving this demo is to make sure of the layout and more of a mock up of their website. After finalizing, the package would have logo designing as well.

**I want to represent this with a blend of the client's domain name/company name.**

I want the best user experience for my clients even when there are going through the demo/mock up of their company.

Comment: How can "those who do not have a logo" have a logo for you to represent?

Comment: @Andrew Leach   "I have the text - domain name/company name" NO graphic

Comment: Right. I've suggested taking out the confusing sentence. And @thatuxguy has the right answer.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure why you would need to go much beyond a simple image placeholder and some copy within that states "Company Logo". As long as you've given it the amount of real estate the client is expecting, I don't see why they'd have a problem with that as a placeholder.

Comment: What thatuxguy said, a generic image with the text copied over the top. Scaled to size, of course.

Comment: @thatuxguy     Thank you for responding, however, I do not want to go old ways. It me who have the problem for not keeping the generic image place holder. I want the best way to visually display it.

Comment: @jitendra111 so you want to draw their attention to something that currently doesn't exist? *Why* do you need to do this? What is wrong with a standard placeholder image? Just because it's 'the old way' is there a problem with that approach? I don't understand your requirement here.

Answer (score 4):

If the company already has a logo, use that one.

If the company does not yet have a logo, use a mockup like this:

[image]

You could easily change "Your" by the company's name, and adjust the green color to the company's color style if it has that before putting it on your demo website.

Comment: Will that not run the risk of the client spending too much time focusing on the logo rather than then layout? *"Oh I don't want our future logo to be green" / "I don't like that font for our logo"...*

Comment: Then you answer is: "We can get your logo in any color and font. This is just a mockup. Don't spend time focussing on the logo. Try focussing on the layout instead. Creating a final logo is something we will do in a later stage."
It's all about communication. A mockup or a demo website is just e means to get a certain message across. It  helps the communication. But it will never tell everything.

Comment: Totally agree, that's why an empty placeholder is usually used for such things. But hey, your answer is a good option for the OP's actual question, it's just the question itself that seems misplaced IMO.

Comment: Commonly [**light grey**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nprmg.jpg) is used to make the image appear neutral and indicate that it is just a placeholder. Anyway I think that the text "Your logo goes here" will communicate to most clients that the displayed image is not the proposed logo.

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to place a grayed out logo of the client against placing a placeholder for logo. It helps them relate to the wireframe more closely and have an ownership feeling as well.

Comment: "ownership feeling" Thats what I am looking for. Please give some more info about this " ownership feeling"

Comment: @jitendra111 well I don't have a direct link to something which will give more details on this. But what it means is, they can relate to the design more than having a common art work in place of logo. Company owners are very proud of their logo and they want to see that logo mark is certain places and their app or website is one such place. It is this mark that they relate more closely to the design and treat it as something associated with their company and not the design org.